# Stuck to Create Cursor

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cursor

I want to update my value salary.

For example, if @sex = 'F' then only the employee that have sex F will be updated the other is same as before

```
ALTER procedure spEmployeeJamKerja (@sex varchar(1))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @temp int
    DECLARE @fname nvarchar(20)

    DECLARE femaleEmpCursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT e.fname, SUM(W.hours) AS TOTAL
        FROM employee e, works_on w
        WHERE e.sex = @sex AND e.ssn = W.ssn
        GROUP BY e.ssn,e.fname

    OPEN femaleEmpCursor

    FETCH NEXT FROM femaleEmpCursor INTO @fname, @temp

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
        IF(@temp > 20)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE employee
            SET salary = salary + (@temp*5)
            WHERE sex = @sex
        END
        ELSE IF (@temp <= 20)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE employee
            SET salary = salary + ((@temp-1)*4)
            WHERE sex = @sex
        END 
    END
END

CLOSE femaleEmpCursor;
DEALLOCATE femaleEmpCursor;
```

After I try my stored procedure, the query never stops, like an unlimited loop. Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: there are several things wrong with it, but I have to ask, why would you use a `cursor` for this?

Comment: because each employee have different work hour , so i use this to update every employee salary in my DB @Lamak

Comment: the cursor is completely unnecessary, you can even see that you are not using the employee name in your update, so it's updating every single employee of that sex every time (which would be the right way to do it, no cursor at all)

Comment: ok, posted an answer with a set base solution

Comment: I would highly recommend not storing ssn in clear text...this is highly sensitive data and it should always be encrypted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not fetching inside the loop, so it's just using the same values over and over.  Just repeat your fetch statement inside the loop.

```
FETCH NEXT FROM femaleEmpCursor INTO @fname,@temp
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            IF(@temp>20)
            BEGIN
                UPDATE employee
                SET salary = salary + (@temp*5)
                WHERE sex = @sex
            END
        ELSE IF (@temp<=20)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE employee
            SET salary = salary + ((@temp-1)*4)
            WHERE sex = @sex
        END </pre>

        FETCH NEXT FROM femaleEmpCursor INTO @fname,@temp
    END
```

There is probably a better way to do it, but I think this answers the question.

Comment: But a cursor is not needed for this. It is a single update statement turned into something unnecessarily slower by introducing looping. And it will update every row in the table each pass through.

Answer (score 2):

You absolutely don't need a cursor for this, there are different set based ways to solve your issue. Here's one alternative:

```
UPDATE e
SET e.salary =  e.salary + 
                CASE 
                    WHEN Total > 20 THEN Total*5 
                    WHEN Total <= 20 THEN (Total -1)*4
                END
FROM employee e
INNER JOIN (SELECT ssn, SUM([hours]) Total 
            FROM works_on
            GROUP BY ssn) w
    ON e.ssn = w.ssn
WHERE sex = @sex;
```

Comment: thanks sir, it's helpfull , im just learning sqlserver and my knowledge not good enough ...

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of providing another option here is another way you could do this using a cte.

```
with EmployeeData as
(
    select SUM(W.hours) AS TOTAL
        , e.ssn
    from employee e
    join works_on w on e.ssn = W.ssn
    where e.sex = @sex 
    group by e.ssn
        ,e.fname
)

update e
    set salary = 
        Case when ed.Total > 20 
            then salary + (ed.Total * )
        else salary + ((ed.Total - 1) * 4)
        end
from Employee e
join EmployeeData ed on ed.ssn = e.ssn
where e.sex = @sex
```